# ZPL: How to vertically stack each letter or Character in a data value on a label

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

I have a piece of data like this: `ABCDEF`

Using ZPL (Zibra Programming Language), how can I format the value to print like this:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

I am able to rotate text but cannot find a command which will give me the above result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ^FPV

```
^XA  
^FO100,50^A0N,30,30^FPV,10^FDABCDEF^FS  
^XZ
```

This will also work for Unicode characters that utilize the multibyte shaping.

Comment: This is close: It comes out horizontal on the label. I need it to be vertical on the label.

Comment: @Altitude do you have some ZPL that is rotating your label? The code from banno looks good

Comment: The command has additional options shown in the ZPL manual. Without seeing your ZPL I can't guess how to fix.

Comment: I changed `A0N` to `A0B` and it worked. Thanks a lot!!